# django link to another page does render new page

Tags: python, django

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to click a link on my page and then be redirected to another of my pages.

**login.html:**

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Login</h1>
{% if message %}
<div>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'new_user' %}">New user</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**new_user.html:**

```
{% block body %}
<h1>New user</h1>
{% if message %}
<div>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'new_user' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input name="email" type="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py in main app:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("orders.urls")),
    path("new_user/", include("users.urls")),
    path("login/", include("users.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

**urls.py in users:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("new_user", views.new_user_view, name="new_user")
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "users/login.html", {"message": None})
    context = {
        "user": request.user
    }
    return render(request, "users/user.html", context)


def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "users/login.html", {"message": "Invalid credentials."})


def new_user_view(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "users/new_user.html", {"message": "Invalid credentials."})
```

**Behavior:**
What happens is I go to `localhost:8000/login` press the link for a new user, my browser redirects me to `localhost:8000/new_user` but is still rendering login.html and not new_user.html

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("orders.urls")),
    path("new_user/", include("users.urls")),
    path("login/", include("users.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

to this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("orders.urls")),
    path("", include("users.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

All URLs from `users` will be included.

`path("new_user/", include("users.urls"))` would result in additional prefix `new_user` for **all the urls** from `users`. In this case `localhost:8000/new_user` matches **index** page from `users` app. You can try accessing `localhost:8000/new_user/new_user` with current configuration - it will render the page you're expecting.